# Irregularities in beacon scan detections

Tags: ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, eddystone

I have been testing Battery consumption of my Beacon detector app in Android using Android Beacon Library. The configurations I set are these -

1) Background Scan Rate - 110 ms
2) Background Between Scan Rate - 10000ms
3) Foreground Scan Rate - 110ms
4) Foreground Between Scan Rate - 10000ms
5) Advertising Rate of Beacon emission - Low Latency (10 Hz)
6) No power saving class used
7) Detecting Eddystone UID beacons

I have tested this configuration for 16 hours with other beacons(all emitting at same 10 Hz frequency) around.

The battery consumption is something I expected however the beacon detection frequency is something I don't understand. There are time periods when beacons are rarely detected at all. 
I observed 2 phases -
1) 1 hour period where there were around 400 detections
2) 2 hour period where there were around 12-15 detections

This happened in cycles. 
What can be the reason? 
Is it something related to Android 5.0 new scanning API's?
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With such a short scan cycle of 110ms, a huge factor of whether you detect a beacon transmitting at 10 Hz will be timing and luck.

Consider that:

- It takes a finite amount of time to start scanning, so the effective scan period will probably be < 100ms
- It takes a finite amount of time for a beacon packet to be transmitted over the air, and if scanning is not started (or stops) while it is in transit, you will not get a detection.
- Beacon transmitters do not send out packets at regular intervals.  They tend to be bunched together or spaced irregularly as the bluetooth transmitter hops channels.
- Even under the best of circumstances with a scan left on constantly without being stopped, only ~90% of packets get received.

Add all of the factors up together, and I am not surprised to see large variations in the number of packets detected.  There are just too many variables outside your control to make it predictable.  If you want more predictability, I would extend the scan period to be at least 1 second.

Comment: Considering all the above scenarios, the test results show that the number of beacon packets detected for a short scan- short between scan period was much higher than number of beacon packets detected for a long scan - long between scan period with the constant ratio between scan period and between scan period. So if beacon detection is concerned with same scan duration for both cases, I received much higher beacon detections for the short scan period case. From the original question, I don't really get it that the cycle pattern of high detection and low detection is based on luck.